# Google Script for Sending Email

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

Is there a way to create a document through google script and automatically put it in a pre-designated shared file folder so that other can open it up?  I'm using the results from a form spreadsheet to make this document but I'm having trouble with this one aspect of google script.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the recipient of the email permission to edit the file:

```
file.addEditor(emailtogoto);
```

... or just view it:

```
file.addViewer(emailtogoto);
```

If the *name* of the shared folder is 'OUR FILE FOLDER', you probably don't mean to use `DocsList.getFolderById()`. You should be using [`DocsList.getFolder(path)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#getFolder%28String%29) instead:

```
var sharedFolder = DocsList.getFolder('OUR FILE FOLDER');
```

You cannot directly attach a google document, but you could attach a pdf version.

```
var pdf = file.getAs("application/pdf"); 
MailApp.sendEmail(emailtogoto, 'Thank you for your using this form!  Here is your file', file.getName()+'\n'+file.getUrl(), {attachments: pdf});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this sample script a while ago to demonstrate all the features available in [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) and [DocsList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/) services, I think in contains about everything you need for the use case you describe (see comments in code)

```
function testDocCreate(){
  try{
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder("testFolder"); // check if shared folder already exist, if not just do it !
  }catch(err){
    folder = DocsList.createFolder("testFolder").addEditor('editorEmailAdress');// or addViewer ...
  }
  // now that our shared testfolder exists we van create files in it that will inherit all sharing properties
  var fileId = DocumentApp.create('testFileName').getId();// create as a text document
  var fileUrl = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).getUrl();
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(fileId);

  file.addToFolder(folder); // share it by moving into the right folder
  file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());// remove the newly created file from your root folder so it won't appear twice

  Logger.log(fileUrl); // send this url to your user and eventually add a pdf copy to your email like below

  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(); // this is the pdf file

  var attach_to_send = {fileName: 'testFileName.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'}; // create an attachment object

  MailApp.sendEmail('editorEmailAdress', "here is the document I've shared with you (url & pdf copy)", 'Your doc available here : '+fileUrl, {attachments:[attach_to_send]});
}
```